# Unable to use wifi in MPLAB Harmony v3

Tags: wifi, tcp-ip, mplab-harmony

I just got started with PIC32MZ curiosity development board with MRF24WN0MA Wi-Fi Module and MPLAB Harmony v3. I am unable to find drivers for wi-fi module (including ATWIN1500c) in harmony v3. Attached is an image of driver layer options which only includes Ethernet support. Harmony v2 used to support wi-fi. How do I use Wi-fi in Harmony v3 ?

[image: MPLAB Harmony TCP IP drivers]

Comment: Why not ask on the harmony forum? V3 is pretty beta yet, isn't it? Frankly, Amazon freertos examples are probably a better starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I received response on Github, where harmony v3 project is being tracked, confirming Wi-Fi support was yet to be added to v3 and recommended continue using v2.